Representation exposure on an int method
This function exposes the value of worldSize, so it is a form of representation exposure:
/**
 * Returns the size of the simulation world.
 * Used for documentation ONLY
 * Should not have representation exposure
 *
 * @return The size of the simulation world.
 */
public int getWorldSize() 
{
    int clone = this.worldSize;
    return clone;
}

I have multiple of these functions in a project, and am only using them for documentation. I am wondering if its possible to obtain the same result without exposing the values of the integers directly.
I have used .clone() or Arrays.copyOf() in the past, but both of those are not for int type functions.

"I have multiple of these functions in a project, and am only using them for documentation." - So those methods are unused? If so: remove them. --- The implementation is pointless. It is identical to just return this.worldSize (even if worldSize is of type Integer).

Yes, however because the documentation is what gets published, it doesnt have access to private functions and worldSize is private: this is what I get back "The field Simulation.worldSize is not visible"

Primitive values are copied
There is no representation exposure in this case because the value is a primitive int type, not an object. The value is automatically copied. Unlike an object reference or an array, there is no reference shared that could be used to modify the original value. This is just a simple getter function. You could just simplify it as:
public int getWorldSize() {
    return this.worldSize;
}


Good answer. Also, if appropriate, a member field can be made immutable by declaring as final. This provides direct access without ability to change the value. Taking that idea further, all member fields of a record are shallowly immutable.

Oke, thank you very much for the further expansion.
